# PHP If Else Statement Url Issue

Tags: php

I have a little problem here and would be glad if anyone can help. I need some advise what operator or script should I use in this case. When my url change from `127.0.0.1/index.php` to `127.0.0.1/index.php?s=abracadabra` the:

```
if($host == '127.0.0.1/index.php') {
    echo'class="active"';
} else {
}
```

won't work. I mean it jumps to the `else` statement. I want it to put the `class="active"` even the url change from `127.0.0.1/index.php` to `127.0.0.1/index.php?s=abracadabra`. Can anyone help?

Comment: what's in $host

Comment: replace if statement like this  `if(empty ($_GET))` as if any query parameter is added it will go to the else pase

Comment: Use strpos() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `parse_url` and then compare

```
<?php

  echo parse_url('127.0.0.1/index.php?s=abracadabra', PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
127.0.0.1/index.php
```

**Update:**

```
<?php

$host = parse_url('127.0.0.1/index.php?s=abracadabra', PHP_URL_PATH);

if($host === '127.0.0.1/index.php') {
   echo'class="active"';
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
class="active"
```

Comment: care to comment . so only i can able to correct my mistake . @down-voter

Comment: Maybe a troll gave you down vote :P but thanks bro. Huge help :)

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @CuriousMan